# javascript - show if user logged to facebook

Tags: javascript, facebook, client-side

I want to check if a user is logged in facebook (not necessarily from my site).
when i debug my script i see that it fails to execute FB.getLoginStatus().
I also tried other FB functions, but it seems it doesn't recognize any of them except for FB.init. why do they fail? any help would be appreciated

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js">
</script>    
<script type="text/javascript">   
           window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
              FB.init({
                appId      : 'my_app_id', // App ID
                status     : true, // check login status
                cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
                xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
              });
            };

            // Load the SDK Asynchronously
            (function(d){
              var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
              js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
              js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
              d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
            }(document));
        function GetFBLoginStatus() {
        debugger;
        window.fbAsyncInit()
                alert("get status");
        FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
            alert("inside call back function"); 
            if (response.status === 'connected') {
              //  var uid = response.authResponse.userID;
               // var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken; 
             //   alert("Connected FBID = " + uid);
            } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') { 
                alert("not_authorized"); 
            } else {
                alert("Not Logged into facebook");
            }
            return true;
        }, true)
    } 
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

### EDIT

You seems to have omitted something important in your code, please, try with this, it works for me:

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.init({
    appId      : '', // App ID
    status     : true, // check login status
    cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
    xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
  });

  // Here we subscribe to the auth.authResponseChange JavaScript event
  FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange', function(response) {
    // Here we specify what we do with the response anytime this event occurs. 
    if (response.status === 'connected') {
      // logged into the app
    alert('logged');
    } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
      // In this case, the person is logged into Facebook, but not into the app
    alert('not authorized but logged into fb')
    } else {
      // not logged into Facebook
    alert('not logged');
    }
  });
  };
  // Load the SDK asynchronously
  (function(d){
   var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
   if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
   js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
   js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
   ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
  }(document));
```

Last thing: pay attentions to "duplicate questions" in few hours

### END EDIT

That's your code?
This 'my_app_id'

```
 appId      : 'my_app_id', // App ID
```

it's a value that fb will generate when you will create an app, you need this number before everything.

If you aren't a web developer (needed to create an app), you can go [here](https://developers.facebook.com/), after you join the developer team, you can create an app and get your app id. Enough clear?

Comment: i am registered as a developer and have app_id is just didn't publish it

Comment: @user2512231 Please check the update. Anyway from the javascript code everyone can see the app id..

Comment: got it. and thanks for the quick answers.
i used the updated code but i get the following error:
Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App&#039;s settings. It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App&#039;s domains.

does it concern the configuration of my app?

Comment: @user2512231 Probably yes, you need to fill the Website with Facebook Login, be sure to add the protocol to and then retry

Comment: @user2512231 No, the protocol don't seems to be necessary but the app domain seems needed to "Enable auth on domain and subdomain(s) (e.g., "example.com" will enable *.example.com)"